# How to round off to only seconds (remove milliseconds)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the below countdown clock to round of to seconds removing the milliseconds.

Any advise please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Set the date we're counting down to
  var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 1, 2018 00:00:01").getTime();


  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor(distance % (1000 * 60)) / (1000)


    // Display the result in the element with id ="timmer"
    document.getElementById("timmer").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";


  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Tried SimpleDateFormat?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
var seconds = Math.floor(distance % (1000 * 60)) / (1000);
```

Correct way:

```
var seconds = Math.floor(distance % (1000 * 60) / (1000));
```

Why?

Because you wrap up the `Math.floor` too soon.

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 1, 2018 00:00:01").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function(){

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor ((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor(distance % (1000 * 60) / (1000));
    // CHANGES HERE ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


    // Display the result in the element with id ="timmer"
    document.getElementById("timmer").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";


}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="timmer"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the number of full minutes you have to divide the number of total seconds by 60 (60 seconds/minute):

```
var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
```

And to get the remaining seconds you have to multiply the full minutes with 60 and subtract from the total seconds:

```
var seconds = time - minutes * 60;
```

Now if you also want to get the full hours too, divide the number of total seconds by 3600 `(60 minutes/hour * 60 seconds/minute)` first, then calculate the remaining seconds:

```
var hours = Math.floor(time / 3600);
time = time - hours * 3600;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution can be to use parseInt(seconds)

Answer (score 0):

How to remove milliseconds: I'm not sure about the performance, but I'm using modulus and subtraction like this.

```js
const timeInMilliseconds = Date.now();
const timeInSeconds = timeInMilliseconds - (timeInMilliseconds % 1000);
```